# Android double tap bitmap image

Tags: android, double, zooming, tap

How to zoom a Bitmap image while double tab in android?

Comment: Refer this url http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/how-to-listen-double-tap-on-imageview-t6234.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. but i need the image zoom.

Comment: Hmmm, Refer my Updated Answer.... friend

Answer (score 0):

You can implement DoubleTapListener.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a class which extends from OnGestureListener and onoubleTapListener

Step 2: Now override the method onDoubleTap, in this method write the code what you want to do when the user double zoom

```
  public static class MyClass implements OnGestureListener, OnDoubleTapListener {
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        }

        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            return false;
        }

        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
        }

        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
enter code here
```